# How big of a HDD can a Mid 2010 Mac Pro handle?

Tags: mac-pro, hdd

I heard somewhere that the maximum HDD size that my Mid 2010 Mac Pro can handle is 4TB.  Is this correct?  If not, how big can I go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that they can't address a larger drive, it's that the screw holes don't fit the 'sleds' that the drives are mounted on.

OWC sell replacements - http://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/MPRODBKTLG6/ though I have no idea if they ship outside the US, or indeed if that would be worth it.

Standard sled - 4 mount points.

[image]

6TB compatible sled - 6 mount points

[image]

Pics from OWC [no affiliation]

Comment: Does this mean that I am correct in thinking that 4TB is the biggest I can go without replacing the sleds as well?

Comment: or doing a little DIY, yes. Though, I have heard reports of some 6TB drives being made now with holes in the old standard locations.

Comment: Without modification, you can get 4x4TB in there. With a little, but not much extra jiggery-pokery, you can also get an SSD in the spare optical bay, or even one on the PCIe bus. I've 6 drives in mine, 4 HD, 1 SSD, 1 superdrive.

Answer (score -1):

The OS X HFS+ Operating System will max out around 8 EB (Exabytes)

To put that into perspective:

8EB = 8,000 Petabytes

1 Petabyte = 1,000 Terrabytes

1 TB = 1,000 GB

In other words...

8 EB = 8 Million TB or 2 million of your 4 TB Hard Drives.  I hope you have room under your desk.

However, a 4 TB drive will easily be installed or you could opt for one of the new [8 TB Helium Drives](http://amzn.to/21DidG3).

Comment: Right now I have no hard drive on the Mac Pro, and fixing that is why I'm asking the question.

Comment: The question is **not** about the supported file system size. Several Mac models had some limitations regarding hdd size and/or form factor due to limitations/bugs of the hdd controller or design height.

Comment: @klanomath  Does a Mac Pro take a 3.5 inch drive? Then what is the issue with design height?  Can you point to a tech document referencing the limitation?  48bit LBA supports about 128PB so are you saying that Apple somehow doesn't conform to the SATA Standard?

Comment: @Allan Apple officially supports 2 TB (and smaller) drives in this Mac Pro. The asking person wants to know if drives > 2 TB are also supported. Answering this question positively I would provide either own experience and/or other persons experiences and/or a technical document published by Apple/3rd party. A well known example of an "artificially" limited Mac is the [Apple Power Macintosh G4 933 (QS 2002)](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/powermac_g4/specs/powermac_g4_933_qs.html)!

Comment: @klanomath You mentioned "design height" and "limitation and bugs in controller"  That's what I am responding to.  Apple "official support" was written when 2TB was the largest.  A SATA 1 controller can handle at least 128PB and HFS+ can handle 8EB.  Why wouldn't it support it again?

Comment: In terms of 'design height' the sleds from the 3,1 & 4/5,1 are not interchangeable. They look pretty similar if you don't put them side by side, but they don't work. That was something I only discovered when I got a 4,1 to replace my 3,1 & thought I could just swap the sleds over.